# How to reveal the values of macros ($(var)) in Azure Pipelines yaml?

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I am attempting to discern the values of some [macro variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#macro-syntax-variables) (e.g. `$(var)`) in my Azure DevOps Pipeline, by outputting their values to the console logs.

This is the YAML code in my Pipeline definition:

```
- task: XamariniOS@2
  inputs:
    solutionFile: '**/*.sln'
    configuration: Release
    buildForSimulator: false
    packageApp: true
    runNugetRestore: false
    args: /p:OutputPath="$(Build.BinariesDirectory)"
    signingIdentity: $(APPLE_CERTIFICATE_SIGNING_IDENTITY)
    signingProvisioningProfileID: $(APPLE_PROV_PROFILE_UUID)
```

And this is my YAML code to try to output the values to the console (it invokes PowerShell directly).

```
- powershell: |
    Write-Host "Build.BinariesDirectory: $(Build.BinariesDirectory)"
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work; I've also tried using Bash instead of PowerShell.

```
Line |
   2 |  Write-Host "Build.BinariesDirectory: $(Build.BinariesDirectory)"
     |                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | The term 'Build.BinariesDirectory' is not recognized as the name of a
     | cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
     | spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that
     | the path is correct and try again.
```

How can one reveal the values for these macro variables in Azure DevOps?

Comment: How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question,  If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: OK turns out it was a mistake on my part in writing the YAML. I had copied the variable 
 name (Build.BinariesDirectory) from a bad source and had copied an invisible bad character that was causing it to trip.

Answer (score 0):

> How to reveal the values of macros ($(var)) in Azure Pipelines yaml?

I have test your powershell task, it works fine on my side. Please check my YAML file:

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

steps:

- powershell: |
    Write-Host "Build.BinariesDirectory: $(Build.BinariesDirectory)"
```

The test result:

[image]

If it still not work for you, please share the build log in your question.

Besides, if you want use Bash task, the scripts should be `echo $(Build.BinariesDirectory)`:

```
echo 'The value of Build.BinariesDirectory is $(Build.BinariesDirectory)'
```

instead of `Write-Host "Build.BinariesDirectory: $(Build.BinariesDirectory)"`

If I misunderstanding anything for this question, please let me know for free.